# How does empty return statement in conditional statement functions?

Tags: javascript, function

Learning JS from MDN Docs came across code in "functions section".
Not able to understand what does `return;` in the below code accomplish

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return; // what does this do? 
  console.log('begin: ' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

`Output`

```
'begin: 3'
'begin: 2'
'begin: 1'
'begin: 0'
'end: 0'
'end: 1' // why are these printing
'end: 2' // this one
'end: 3' // this one
```

I understood first 5 lines of output, but not able to understand why `end: 0,1,2,3` are coming?

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` terminates the *current* function, and returns control flow to the caller.

When `foo(3);` is called, the function is initialized with an `i` parameter of 3. It fails the `if` statement, prints `begin: 3`, and then calls `foo(3 - 1);`. At this point, the current function (the one with an `i` parameter of 3) is paused until the `foo(3 - 1);` call completes.

`foo(2);` prints `begin: 2`, and then pauses while calling `foo(1)`.

`foo(1)` prints `begin: 1`, and then pauses while calling `foo(0)`.

`foo(0)` prints `begin: 0`, and returns: it terminates, and yields control flow back to its caller, the function call of `foo(1)`.

`foo(1)` resumes, and continues executing, printing `end: 1`. That's the end of the function block, so the `foo(1)` function call ends, yielding control flow back to the `foo(2)` function call.

`foo(2)` resumes, printing `end: 2`, then terminates, yielding control flow back to `foo(3)`. Then `foo(3)` prints `end: 3`, and terminates.

---

`return` only terminates the current function. The only way to terminate *all* calling functions (until a `catch` is encountered) would be to throw an error:

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    throw new Error();
  console.log('begin: ' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you trace the code :

```
foo(3)
|-- "begin 3"
|-- foo(2)
|   |-- "begin 2"
|   |-- foo(1)
|   |   |-- "begin 1"
|   |   |-- foo(0)
|   |   |   |-- "begin 0"
|   |   |   |-- foo(-1) // returns nothing
|   |   |   |-- "end 0"
|   |   |-- "end 1"
|   |-- "end 2"
|-- "end 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` is used to complete a function call and pass execution back to parent

```
function foo(i) {
if (i < 0)
  return; // prevents further code from being executed, the execution is returned to the parent function from where foo is called
console.log('begin: ' + i);
foo(i - 1);
console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a recursive function.when base condition fill then it execute the other statements.In your case it is console.log('end: ' + i);